# Init application and use Selected value in connectOutlet

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I got problem with initialization of application.
I create jsfiddle which simply works on my desktop but not on jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/zDSnm/

I hope you will catch the idea.

On the beginining od my aplication I have to get some values from rest and values to Ember.Select.
Depends on what is choosen all my connectOutlets functions use this value.

Here I get some data from REST

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/emberjs/ember.js/contributors',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  context: this,
  success: function(response){
    [{login: 'a'},{login: 'b'}].forEach(function(c){
        this.allContributors.addObject(App.Contributor.create(c))
    },this);
  }
})
```

and put it to my Select View:

```
{{view Ember.Select
contentBinding="App.Contributor.allContributors"
selectionBinding="App.Contributor.selectedContributor"
    optionLabelPath="content.login"
optionValuePath="content.id" }} 
{{outlet}}
```

And in every of my route I need to use this value, which is selected in this selection box

```
index : Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/',
    connectOutlets: function(router){
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('oneContributor',App.Contributor.selectedContributor);
    }
})
```

I'd also add observer to this selectedContributor value which calls connectOutlets of currentState (I know I shouldn't do this but I don't know why and how should I do this in properly way)

```
App.Contributor.reopenClass({
    //...
refresh : function(){
    App.router.currentState.connectOutlets(App.router);
}.observes('selectedContributor'), 
    //...
```

I hope there is some good way to solve such problem.
If there is something not clear please leave comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to show the currently selected contributor. One way to do it is to listen for a change in the selected contributor and send a `transitionTo` action to the Router.

First the router:

```
   index : Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/',

        showContibutor: Ember.Route.transitionTo('show'),
        showNoneSelected: Ember.Route.transitionTo('noneSelected'),

        connectOutlets: function(router){
          router.applicationController.connectOutlet({ name: 'contributors', context: App.Contributor.find() });
        },

        // if no contributor is selected, the router navigates here
        // for example, when a default option "Make a selection" is selected.
        noneSelected: Ember.Route.extend({
           route: '/'
        }),

        show: Ember.Route.extend({
           route: '/:contributor_id'
             connectOutlets: function(router, context){
             router.applicationController.connectOutlet({name: 'contributor', context: context})
           },

           exit: function(router) {
             // This will remove the App.ContributorView from the template. 
             router.applicationController.disconnectOutlet('view');
           }
        })
    })
```

with a template for `App.ContributorsView`:

```
{{view Ember.Select
  contentBinding="controller"
  selectionBinding="controller.selectedContributor"
  optionLabelPath="content.login"
  optionValuePath="content.id"}} 

{{outlet}}
```

and an `ArrayController` to manage contributors:

```
App.ContributorsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  onSelectedContributorChange: function() {
     var selectedContributor = this.get('selectedContributor');
     if (selectedContributor) {
       App.router.send('showContributor', selectedContributor);
     } else {
       App.router.send('showNoneSelected');
     }
  }.observes('selectedContributor')
});
```

---

The user a selects a contributor and the contributorsController tells the router to show the view for the contributor (i.e, show the view `App.ContributorView` with context `selectedContributor`).

```
App.ContributorView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'contributor'
});
```

controller for selected contributor:

```
App.ContributorController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  // define events and data manipulation methods
  // specific to the currently selected contributor.
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

UPDATE: If you need to show the first record by default, the `noneSelected` route should look like this:

```
        noneSelected: Ember.Route.extend({
           route: '/',
           connectOutlets: function(router){
             var context = router.contributorsController.get('content.firstRecord');
             router.applicationController.connectOutlet({name: 'contributor', context: context})
           }
        })
```

And define firstRecord in ContributorsController:

```
App.ContributorsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  firstRecord: function() {
    return this.get('content') && this.get('content').objectAt(0)
  }.property('content.[]')
});
```

Haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for answer, this showed me how to make it's more clean but dont solve my basic problem. When I load page I see:STATEMANAGER: Entering root.index 
STATEMANAGER: Entering root.index.noneSelected and Select is filled with data. But I like to go to the first selected. Should I select this value manualy after call $.ajax?

Comment: This is a bit trickier as whatever method you use to select the first option, the router will first navigate to `index` and **then** navigate to the first element: `#/:first_element_id`. Therefore the the user will still be able to go to the `noneSelected` state by pressing the browser back button. But to answer your question see update above.

Comment: I've got also other problem
I like to have to states of router: A and B which have to get this selected value as context.
when I type App#/A I'd like to get i.e. details of selected user
but when I type App#/B I'd like to get repos of this user.

There is also problem that I don't like to make changes in my path

Comment: I tried you update code and it's not working. router.contributorsController.get('content') returns empty set and there is exception: Property 'firstObject' of object  is not a function

Comment: I checked and should be fistObject (without brackets), but I tried and this set empty object as context

Comment: Thanks for all help. I tried your update in solution and it's not working :/